Love Hate Eclipse 4 Rcp Mac Export
I know there has been discussion around this topic, I am trying to better understand why the latest version of Eclipse RCP will not allow a user to create a simple RCP application and use the product export wizard to create a mac executable, without this what is the purpose of building apps on an Eclipse RCP, I've been using this technology for almost 20 years and its always been painful, does anyone know how I can create an executable for my rcp app that runs on mac or can suggest another rich desktop platform? Clicking the export wizard finish button just does nothing, no logs nothing. Maybe get creative and find the native launcher for eclipse itself and try to add my plugins in there but that defeats the purpose, anyone know how to do this?

[tag:tycho] is used to build Eclipse RCPs, this handles macOS apps with no problem - I use it every day.

Thank you @greg-449 - Have not tired it yet but should be able to setup a simple project, this might also resolve my problem of maven artifacts being manually brought into plugins.

@greg-449 I downloaded an example of Tycho product export and added the mac os environment and failed to create an executable, said it was missing some runtime. It's sad I grea up on eclipse it might be on my tail end.

There are all sorts of things that could cause that, maybe a target platform that doesn't include the macOS components, but that is just a guess with no information.
